# How does one retrieve selected area from QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I need my QGraphicsView to react on user selection - that is, change display when user selects area inside it. How can i do that?

As far as i can tell, selection in Qt Graphics framework normaly works through selection of items. I haven't found any methods/properties that touch on selected area, save for [QGraphicsVliew::rubberBandSelectionMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#rubberBandSelectionMode-prop), which does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some going through documentation, i found different solution.

In `QGraphicsView` there is a [rubberbandChanged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#rubberBandChanged) signal, that contained just the information i wanted to use. So, i handled it in a slot, resulting in the handler of following form:

```
void 
MyImplementation::rubberBandChangedHandler(QRect rubberBandRect, QPointF fromScenePoint, QPointF toScenePoint)
{
    // in default mode, ignore this
    if(m_mode != MODE_RUBBERBANDZOOM)
        return;

    if(rubberBandRect.isNull())
    {
        // selection has ended
        // zoom onto it!
        auto sceneRect = mapToScene(m_prevRubberband).boundingRect();
        float w = (float)width() / (float)sceneRect.width();
        float h = (float)height() / (float)sceneRect.height();

        setImageScale(qMin(w, h) * 100);
        // ensure it is visible
        ensureVisible(sceneRect, 0, 0);

        positionText();
    }

    m_prevRubberband = rubberBandRect;
}
```

To clarify: my implementation zooms on selected area. To that effect class contains `QRect` called `m_prevRubberband`. When user stop selection with rubberband, parameter `rubberBandRect` is null, and saved value of rectangle can be used.

On related note, to process  mouse events without interfering with rubber band handling, `m_prevRubberband` can be used as a flag (by checking it on being null). However, if mouseReleaseEvent is handled, check must be performed before calling default event handler, because it will set `m_prevRubberband` to null rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`qgraphicsscenemouseevent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html).

On `MousePress` save the current position and on `MouseRelease` you can compute a bounding rect using the current position and the `MousePress` position.

This gives you the selected area.
If you need custom shapes you could track the mouse movement (`MouseMove`) to get the shape.

An Example that uses [`qgraphicsscenemouseevent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html) can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-diagramscene-diagramscene-cpp.html).